# Get Data Object Underlying Angular $resource get() Response Object

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

### Problem

$resource does not return raw JSON object

#### Explanation

When I use the get() method on the ng $resource class, I am returned a Resource object that has the data I want, along with extras like $promise and $resolved.

For instance I have:

```
Resource {
id: "5400c95b70726518d1020000", 
title: "Treeview", 
objective: null, 
nodes: Array[1], 
$promise: Object…}
$promise: Object
$resolved: trueid: "5400c95b70726518d1020000"nodes: Array[1]
0: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]objective: nulltitle: "Treeview"__proto__: Resource}
```

Which I am sure is really useful to a lot of people, but what I really want is:

`{id: "5400c95b70726518d1020000", title: "Treeview", objective: null, nodes: Array[1]}`

Is there an easy way to access the object I wanted to return without all of the decorations?

Comment: Did the answer below help you?